# Getting not_authed slack error on web api call though token is passed

Tags: slack-api, slack

I have successfully added an application in slack api with the permission scope set **administer the teams**:

I have generated the token from **Legacy token generator** And I am making a api call with the following information from postman.

> endpoint: https://slack.com/api/users.list
>
> method:GET
>
> **Headers:**
>
> key=token
>
> value=token generated

*Its returning me the following Response*

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "not_authed"
}
```

**Trying the same things with curl is working but with POST method and does not works on GET method**

```
curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/users.list --data "token=codehere"
```

Where exactly am I going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with GET too, but you have to pass the properties as URL parameter, not in the header.

Here is an example for the syntax:

```
https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=YOURTOKEN
```

Comment: `{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "missing_scope",
  "needed": "users:read",
  "provided": "admin,identify"
}` I get this error when I try  to make a call directly as you stated.

Comment: Most Slack API methods require your token to have certain scopes attached to it. More details [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes)